# How to debug a C++/CLI library without any errors or warnings?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I made a C++/CLI wrapper for a few tools deriving their functionality from a big C/C++ library. The first 2 tools compile and work fine, I tested this. Then I added another one and everything still compiles without any errors but when it gets to actually using the code, when I press the test button it says "could not load file or assembly" with the name of my wrapper library.

How can I possibly debug this or find out whats wrong?

Comment: This is quite normal, the build system cannot see that your C# EXE project has a dependency on unmanaged DLLs.  You have to either change the Output Directory on the project that generates the unmanaged DLL or add a Post-build event to copy them in the right place.  It is C++, it is supposed to be difficult :)

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely missing a dependent DLL.  If the third tool is compiled into DLL then make sure that DLL is in the same folder as your other binaries.

If this doesn't solve the problem then you can try to find the missing dll using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Comment: Note: Pick the Dependency Walker download matching the bitness of your application code, not your OS.  Usually this means you want 32-bit Dependency Walker, `/CPU:x86` on the .NET project, 32-bit C++ code.